# How do you set pie chart colors in angular-chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am playing with the pie chart in **angular-charts.js**. I have made it so that I can set the data and labels. A watcher function executes whenever something is added or removed from the list of "pie" items.

Labels and data are recognized, but not the color. I have tried a few different spellings.

```
app.controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout, pieItems) {
    $scope.labels = pieItems.labelsItems();
    $scope.data = pieItems.data();


    function watcherFunction(newData) {
        $scope.labels = pieItems.labelsItems(); //just an array of strings. 
        $scope.data = pieItems.data(); //just an array of number values

        $scope.colours = ["rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)",
            "rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)",
            "rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)"] //not working

        $scope.colors = ["rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)",
            "rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)",
            "rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)"] //also not working

    }

    $scope.$watch(pieItems.list, watcherFunction, true);
    $scope.$watch(pieItems.getTitle, watcherFunction, true);

});
```

It seems to generate random colors for the slices. I would like to override this. Surely it must be possible to do this?

Comment: Where are you setting your chart defaults? Can we see that code?

Comment: You don't need to watch `colors` or `colours` array. So, it should declare the `color array` outside of the `watcherFunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS:

```
$scope.colours = ["rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)",
            "rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)",
            "rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)"]
```

Your directive Markup:

```
<canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-colours="colours"></canvas>
```

The docs say you can override default colors by setting the array :

```
Chart.defaults.global.colours
```

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work for me :( It still generates random colors

Comment: sorry. yes it does work :) I had some wrong code. Thanks!

Comment: in my case, i need to set chart-colors. i'm using version 1.1.1

Comment: @Evan I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For version 1.x
There are two ways either object instances or simple RGBA values as string:

```
colors = ["rgba(159,204,0,0.5)","rgba(250,109,33,0.7)","rgba(154,154,154,0.5)"];

colors = [
        {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(159,204,0, 0.2)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(159,204,0, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(159,204,0, 0.8)",
            borderColor: "rgba(159,204,0, 1)",
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(159,204,0, 1)"
        },"rgba(250,109,33,0.5)","#9a9a9a","rgb(233,177,69)"
    ];
```

View:

```
      <canvas id="doughnut"
              class="chart chart-doughnut"
              chart-data="$ctrl.piChartData"
              chart-labels="$ctrl.labels"
              chart-options="$ctrl.options"
              chart-colors="$ctrl.colors"
      >
      </canvas>
```

That's worked for me as mentioned in their docs.

Docs [Link](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/blob/master/README.md)